# Connecting to an existing rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

We are making a site that runs Ruby on Rails.  My teammate, with a better coding knowledge, has made a rails app with a database. He is running code on localhost to develop the site.

He has a mac and I have windows.  I have done all the necessary steps to run ruby and bundles. I have the right versions of everything and all gems installed, but I cannot see the site live on localhost. I made the rails app from an existing folder my teammate sent over to me on a drive.

**Do I need to connect to an existing database somehow or make my own one?** I need help connecting to his existing project. I have all the same folders and routes. Any suggestions?

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users
    resources :posts do
        resources :comments
        member do |variable|
            put "like", to: "posts#upvote"
        end
    end
    resources :pins
    root 'pins#index'
    get 'new' => 'posts#new'
    get 'tags/:tag' => 'posts#index', as: :tag
end
```

Comment: Please provide the error message from your console log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst somewhat of a trivial answer, but nevertheless..

If someone would have sent me their project, these would be the steps I'd take to run it...

1) `cd` into the root of the rails project inside the console. 
2) `bundle` (to install the gems)
3) `bundle exec rake db:migrate` (to migrate the database) 
4) `rails s` (to run the server) 
5) go to the browser and visit `localhost:3000` and see if it works.

But, again, please provide a console log for us to see what is going on.

#### **UPDATE:**

Adding a root route to an app...

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'your_controller#your_action/view'
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Comment: Alright, so bundle exec rake db:migrate doesn't provide any output.  When I run the server here is the output:

Andrews-MacBook-Pro:forum andrewmcfadden$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-07-17 13:33:56] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-07-17 13:33:56] INFO  ruby 2.2.1 (2015-02-26) [x86_64-darwin14]
[2015-07-17 13:33:56] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=53326 port=3000

Comment: forum is the rails app, and I just see the generic "welcome you are riding rails" message, not the site

Comment: You are almost there. The reason you are seeing "welcome to rails" message is because, supposedly, your friend forgot to add the root route inside routes.rb file. Now, tell me what files are inside of your **controllers** and **views** folders respectively and, hopefully, we will fix your issue pretty quickly

Comment: Is there a way to DM you? I tried to upload the screenshot, but don't have enough reputation points

Comment: forum>apps>controllers>concerns>posts_controller.rb & application_controller.rb & comments_controoler.rb & pins_controller.rb

Comment: Awesome, now tell me what is inside of the views folder, like you did with controllers

Comment: forum>apps>views>comments / devise / layouts / pins / posts / vanhawks.html

Comment: Alright, what is inside of the posts and pins folders? From what I am seeing, you, probably , need to add either `root posts#index ` or `root pins#index`  to your **routes.rb** file.

Comment: pins>new.html.haml / _forum.html.haml / index.html.haml
OR
posts>lots of similar html.haml files ; routes.rb is in the config folder

Comment: Yeah, see my update in my post. Try it with either `root posts#index` or `root pins#index`. Go to localhost and see which one works and you are done.

Comment: It was already 'root posts#index'.  Changed to 'root pins#index' with no luck.  posted the code in edited original question

Comment: What happens if you visit `localhost:3000/posts/index` or `localhost:3000/pins/index`. Does it work? or do you get an ExecJs error?

Comment: Routing error with this message: No route matches [GET] "/posts/index" and same situation with it as pins

Comment: Ok, try navigating to `localhost:3000/new`, since this is one of the named routes your friend set in your routes.rb. If it still doesn't work, you'll, I am afraid will have to debug your app's routing on your own, since it will be beyond the scope of this question.